# "Replacing" Calculus with Real Analysis

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, math-history

I am aware that for applications (for many engineers for instance), the "early calculus" is all they really want and need to solve their practical problems. (No need to study notions such as uniform continuity, or view Calculus as theorems based on precise definitions).

However for an aspiring mathematician, could one begin with real analysis, and along the way, introduce the student to many examples? So they would see calculus along the way in the form of concrete examples of the theory, rather than studying calculus first for a number of years, and then learning real analysis separately.

It seems this is a more efficient approach, for a student intending to study mathematics further.

Comment: I've wondered this too before. A first argument is that when a mathematics student fails more abstract courses, they still have the computational tools to efficiently switch to a different study where abstract nonsense is not needed.

Comment: If you're sufficiently smart, of course you can go straight to real analysis. But most people are not sufficiently smart.

Comment: If you can read German, look at the top textbook here:   https://people.math.ethz.ch/~blatter/dlp.html

Comment: A better approach is that you study calculus and include proofs of key theorems like Rolle's, mean value, IVT etc and reserve real analysis for more difficult and abstract topics like metrics spaces, measure theory, Fourier series etc.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an answer in the strict sense of the word on this site (my apologies ... delete if you must).  But, as an analogy, I ended up studying master's level point-set topology before I studied undergraduate analysis and it was the best decision I ever made.

In my analysis class, my peers were worrying about specific examples while I was thinking about the overreaching concepts.   I had an edge.

However, *“Replacing” Calculus with Real Analysis* in the curriculum would mean, IMHO, attacking the problem of "mathematical maturity."

Mathematical maturity might be a problem.  Most undergraduates spend a year, or so, studying calculus while they gather their logical foundations and learn about mathematical argument.

"Out of order" curricular decisions are a good thing at the right time.

So, I'll answer a question with a question:

*How would you prepare a typical 17-year-old student for Analysis before calculus?*

Comment: Answering your question at the end: start with books like Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* for students at the age of 16-17. This is 11-12 of the typical K12 education system and don't ask proofs in the exam (at least not the difficult ones). This helps you teach techniques of calculus and also theory of calculus. Let the students decide which part they want to focus.